# Cannot display images which are linked to a project

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, crud

I have two tables. One is **projects** and the other one is **projects_images**. Every projects can have many images. So in this case I have a foreign key **images_id** linked to the project **id**

My problem is that I cannot display the images which are linked to each project.

**This is my controller:**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Entities\Project;
use App\Entities\ProjectImage;
use DB;

class ProjectsController extends Controller
{
    public function Index (){



    }

    public function Show($id){



        $viewModel['projects'] = Project::find($id);  //Finding the project 
by id and passing and storing the data in projects

        $pid = Project::find($id);

        $viewModel['images'] = ProjectImage::where('images_id', '=', $pid)-
>orderBy('id','desc');

        return view('pages.projects', $viewModel); //passing the variable to 
the view

    }
 }
```

**This is my view:**

```
 <div class="row">
     @foreach($images as $image)
      <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ $image->images_path }}">
    @endforeach
  </div>
```

**And those are my modals**

**Project**

```
namespace App\Entities;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Project extends Model
{

     protected $table = 'projects';

     public function projectImage (){

     return $this->hasMany('App\Entities\ProjectImage','images_id', 'id' );
     }


}
```

And the other one is **ProjectImage**

```
<?php

namespace App\Entities;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ProjectImage extends Model
{

     protected $table = 'projects_images';

     public function project (){

     return $this->belongsTo('App\Entities\Project','images_id', 'id' );
     }


}
```

I am trying to find out where is exactly my mistake. I can save images to the **projects_images** table and they are properly linked to the correct project but I cannot dispaly them in the view when I try to open the project.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I have fixed it.

This is the correct code :

```
 $viewModel['images'] = ProjectImage::where('images_id', '=', $id)->get();
```